# RewriteRule not running

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have put a .htaccess file in `httpdocs/test/`, with two rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^test/reviews/([0-9]+)\-[A-Za-z1-9\-]$ /test/reviews.php?id=$1

DirectoryIndex reviews.php
```

The DirectoryIndex rule works, so I know the file is parsed. However, the address `/test/reviews/123-Bose` results in a 404 error. On my phpinfo file, under apache2hander, there is `mod_rewrite` next to Loaded Modules, so Rewrite has been loaded. Why doesn't `/test/reviews/123-Bose` get rewritten?

EDIT: I have to leave the .htaccess in the /test/ directory.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `.htaccess` file in the *root* folder, not in the subfolder, if you are going to specify the entire base path including `test/` anyway. Also, add a base statement since you don't specify a leading slash:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
...your rules...
```

Comment: How would I do it if I had to leave the .htaccess in the test folder?